# Is it possible to restrict a sql table to only have a single row at the design stage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a simple table as scripted below.

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.KeyNumbers (
  RowId INT IDENTITY
 ,ProFormaNumber NCHAR(10) NULL
 ,SalesOrderNumber NCHAR(10) NULL
 ,PurchaseOrderNumber NCHAR(10) NULL
 ,InvoiceCreditNoteNumber NCHAR(10) NULL
 ,InvoiceNumber NCHAR(10) NULL
 ,PurchaseInvoiceCreditNoteNumber NCHAR(10) NULL
 ,ModifiedDate DATETIME NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_KeyNumbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (RowId)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The table is used to store key document numbers (Invoice number, Sales Order number etc) for the company, and as such only requires a single row.  The main interaction with this table is done through stored procedures so the end use should never need to access it, but I am wondering if there is a way in SQL server to actively restrict the table to have one, and only one row, and to be able to do that at the design stage.

EDIT

Proof that Gordon's suggestion works nicely

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The obvious method uses a trigger on insert to be sure the table is empty.

I've never tried this, but an index on a computed column might also work:

```
alter table dbo.KeyNumbers add OneAndOnly as ('OneAndOnly');

alter table dbo.KeyNumbers add constraint unq_OneAndOnly unique (OneAndOnly);
```

This should generate a unique key violation if a second row is inserted.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I'm going to quickly try this out on a new database and table and I'll let you know.

Comment: Works beautifully, Thank you.  Have edited question to illustrate that it does.

Answer (score 2):

--I think this would be cleaner and utilizes the existing columns

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.KeyNumbers (
  RowId AS (1) PERSISTED
 ,ProFormaNumber NCHAR(10) NULL
 ,SalesOrderNumber NCHAR(10) NULL
 ,PurchaseOrderNumber NCHAR(10) NULL
 ,InvoiceCreditNoteNumber NCHAR(10) NULL
 ,InvoiceNumber NCHAR(10) NULL
 ,PurchaseInvoiceCreditNoteNumber NCHAR(10) NULL
 ,ModifiedDate DATETIME NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_KeyNumbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (RowId)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: .Vincent, thank you for your answer.In many ways I incline to agree with you about it's readability and its simplicity, and have marked it up for that reason. Gordon's answer opened my eyes to an area of SQL I'd not explored before and another new thing learned in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use instead of trigger to accomplish the same..

```
create table test
(
id int
)

create trigger dbo.test_trgr
on dbo.test
instead of insert
as
begin
--here we check table rows,if there are no rows,iinsert..else ignore
if not exists(select 1 from dbo.test)
begin

insert into dbo.test
select * from inserted

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Define one of the columns (any column will do) with:

- a `check` constraint, requiring it to be the value you ultimately want
- a `unique` constraint

For example, if you want the `id` column to have value `1`:

```
create table mytable (
    id int check (id = 1) unique,
    othercol1 text,
    othercol2 int // etc
)
```

Now there can be at most 1 row and it must have id = 1.